# Matching a section of a large text file using Python

Tags: python, regex

I have been manually searching large files produced by running a program. I have been successful at pulling out some blocks of information but I am stuck trying to extract the last three blocks. The structure of the blocks are as below:

Have tried several re expressions with no success such as:

```
v2 = re.findall(r'(?s)\(VFSCAN\) AT TIME =(.*?)100 BUSES WITH LOW VOLTAGE DEVIATION BELOW.*?\s*$',wholefile)
```

wholefile is the entire file that I have read in. The file have several of each of the below sections and I would like to extract them all so that I may locate the last occurrence of an entry such as (`18436 [LENZIE 618.0]   -0.245`). I will then parse the line with the time to determine when this occurred. I have to do the same for "voltage deviation" "voltage", and "frequency". If I find out how to match one variable length, multi line section it should be the same for the others. My problem is knowing when to end the search. I am using the fact that the search should end at the last blank line (hence I use `\s*$`). I am using findall to extract all such sections for voltage deviation for example.

I also have an issue with the VERBOSE definition of the pattern in python. I does not seem to work (below). Am I doing something wrong?

```
(VFSCAN) AT TIME =  1.1800 UP TO  100 BUSES WITH LOW VOLTAGE DEVIATION BELOW -0.200:

X ----- BUS ------ X    VDEV       X ----- BUS ------ X    VDEV
18436 [LENZIE 618.0]   -0.245      18433 [LENZIE 318.0]   -0.245     
18431 [LENZIE 118.0]   -0.214      18432 [LENZIE 218.0]   -0.214     
18435 [LENZIE 518.0]   -0.214      18434 [LENZIE 418.0]   -0.214     

(VFSCAN) AT TIME =  2.6267 UP TO  100 BUSES WITH LOW VOLTAGE BELOW  0.700:

X ----- BUS ------ X    VOLT       X ----- BUS ------ X    VOLT
65191 [BONANZA 24.0]    0.439      65194 [CHAPITA  138]    0.581     
65192 [BONANZA  138]    0.585      65371 [COVE TP  138]    0.694     
66278 [RANGELY  138]    0.698     

(VFSCAN) AT TIME =  6.0632 UP TO  100 BUSES WITH LOW FREQUENCY BELOW 59.600:

X ----- BUS ------ X    FREQ       X ----- BUS ------ X    FREQ
27117 [WTGCP   .600]   59.443      27123 [WTGGE2  .570]   59.490     
27119 [WTGGE   .570]   59.492      26040 [INTERM2G26.0]   59.492     
26039 [INTERM1G26.0]   59.492     

pattern = r"""
(?s)                                                            # Tell Regex to span multiple lines
\(VFSCAN\).*100 BUSES WITH LOW VOLTAGE DEVIATION BELOW -0.200:  # Literal string to serach for
(\s*$).*?                                                        # This search for an empty line
X ----- BUS ------ X    VOLT       X ----- BUS ------ X    VOLT   # Literal string to search            (\d{5}.*).*?                                                         # Multiple lines starting with numbers
\s*$                                                                 # This search ends with an empty line
"""
regex = re.compile(pattern, re.VERBOSE)
```

NEXT DAY 
After trying for a couple more hours I came up with the following. The first one matched everything (not what I need) and the second one which I was sure would work did not match my test file.

First:

```
(?s)^\(VFSCAN\).*100 BUSES WITH LOW VOLTAGE DEVIATION BELOW -0.200:.*(\s*$)?
```

Second:

```
(?m)(?s)^\(VFSCAN\).*100 BUSES WITH LOW VOLTAGE DEVIATION BELOW -0.200:^\s*$^X ----- BUS ------ X    VDEV.*?
(.*?)
^\s*$
```

With these regex I am trying to match the following section of the file completely.

```
(VFSCAN) AT TIME =  1.1800 UP TO  100 BUSES WITH LOW VOLTAGE DEVIATION BELOW -0.200:

X ----- BUS ------ X    VDEV       X ----- BUS ------ X    VDEV
18436 [LENZIE 618.0]   -0.245      18433 [LENZIE 318.0]   -0.245     
18431 [LENZIE 118.0]   -0.214      18432 [LENZIE 218.0]   -0.214     
18435 [LENZIE 518.0]   -0.214      18434 [LENZIE 418.0]   -0.214
```

I need some help to fix the pattern so that I can select the above.

I have problems with the following text. I just want to extract the time and related items in all the square brackets "[]".

```
test3 = r'''(VFSCAN) AT TIME =  1.1800 UP TO  100 BUSES WITH LOW VOLTAGE DEVIATION BELOW -    0.200:

X ----- BUS ------ X    VDEV       X ----- BUS ------ X    VDEV
18436 [LENZIE 618.0]   -0.245      18433 [LENZIE 318.0]   -0.245     
18431 [LENZIE 118.0]   -0.214      18435 [LENZIE 518.0]   -0.214     
18434 [LENZIE 418.0]   -0.214      18432 [LENZIE 218.0]   -0.214     

(VFSCAN) AT TIME =  1.5167 UP TO  100 BUSES WITH LOW VOLTAGE DEVIATION BELOW -0.200:

X ----- BUS ------ X    VDEV       X ----- BUS ------ X    VDEV
69036 [DNLP2G21.575]   -0.414      69038 [DNLP2G22.575]   -0.414     
69040 [DNLP2G23.575]   -0.414      69032 [DNLP1_G1.575]   -0.402     
65460 [DIFICULT 230]   -0.384      69027 [7MIHL G1.575]   -0.355     
69076 [HORIZ_G .575]   -0.303      67237 [MEDBOWCO 115]   -0.301     
67940 [STNDPSVC 230]   -0.300      65976 [MINERS  34.5]   -0.294     
65585 [FT CRK1 34.5]   -0.261      65584 [FT CRK2 34.5]   -0.261     
69073 [HIPLN_G .575]   -0.214     

(VFSCAN) AT TIME =  1.1800 UP TO  100 BUSES WITH LOW VOLTAGE DEVIATION BELOW -0.200:

X ----- BUS ------ X    VDEV       X ----- BUS ------ X    VDEV
65191 [BONANZA 24.0]   -0.572      65192 [BONANZA  138]   -0.434     
65194 [CHAPITA  138]   -0.433      66278 [RANGELY  138]   -0.320     
65371 [COVE TP  138]   -0.302      79265 [CALAMRDG 138]   -0.286     
79400 [DES.MINE 138]   -0.285      65086 [ASHLEY  69.0]   -0.284     
79067 [VERNAL   138]   -0.277      67257 [MOONLAK269.0]   -0.268     
67256 [MOONLAK169.0]   -0.266      79264 [W.RV.CTY 138]   -0.206     

'''
```

When I use findall with the pattern I get.

```
[('1.1800', 'DEVIATION', 'LENZIE 218.0'), ('1.5167', 'DEVIATION', 'HIPLN_G .575'), ('1.1800', 'DEVIATION', 'W.RV.CTY 138')]
```

I should be getting over 30 matched tuples in my list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Regex to extract fields

```
\(VFSCAN\)[^=]*=\s*    # first line of a section: (VFSCAN) AT TIME =  1.1800 UP TO  100 BUSES WITH LOW VOLTAGE DEVIATION BELOW -0.200
(\d*(?:\.\d+)?)        # group 1 - first number of first line: 1.1800
\D+
(\d+)                  # group 2 - second number of first line: 100
[^\d-]+
(-?\d*(?:\.\d+)?)      # group 3 - last number of first line: -0.200
\D+                    # skip second line
(?:                    # a data line: 18436 [LENZIE 618.0] -0.245 18433 [LENZIE 318.0] -0.245
  (?:                  # a data entry: 18436 [LENZIE 618.0] -0.245
    (\d+)              # group 4 - first number in an entry: 18436
    \s+\[
    (.*?)              # group 5 - words in brackets: LENZIE
    (-?\d*(?:\.\d+)?)  # group 6 - number in brackets: 618.0
    \]\s*
    (\S*)              # group 7 - last number (VDEV): -0.245
    \s*
  )+
  (?=[\r\n\s]+|$)
)+
```

`BUSES WITH LOW VOLTAGE DEVIATION BELOW` goes between group 2 and group 3 (`[^\d-]+`). So, you can do one of the below:

#### Option 1

You can capture also this part to check later if it is your desired section. Simply adding parantheses around it, makes it 3th capture group:

`[^\d-]+` => `([^\d-]+)`.

#### Option 2

Or you can change same part of the regex to match only against desired section. In this case, the regex matches only specified section instead of each section:

`[^\d-]+` => `\s+BUSES\s+WITH\s+LOW\s+VOLTAGE\s+DEVIATION\s+BELOW\s+`

If you want to match both the lines:

```
BUSES WITH LOW VOLTAGE DEVIATION BELOW
BUSES WITH LOW FREQUENCY BELOW
```

then, you can write changing part with alternative (`|`) syntax (`(?:...)` means do not capture this group):

`[^\d-]+` => `\s+BUSES\s+WITH\s+LOW\s+(?:VOLTAGE\s+DEVIATION|FREQUENCY)\s+BELOW\s+`

### Performance Improvement

#### Capturing Groups

Unnecesarray capturing groups can be removed such as `(xyz)` => `xyz`, or made non-capturing in this way: `(xyz)` => `(?:xyz)`

#### Unnecessary Optionalities

Changing `.*` to `.+` can cause to some performance increase.

### Improved Regex

The regex below is improved version of the above regex:

```
\(VFSCAN\)[^=]*=\s*    # first line of a section: (VFSCAN) AT TIME =  1.1800 UP TO  100 BUSES WITH LOW VOLTAGE DEVIATION BELOW -0.200
(\d*(?:\.\d+)?)        # group 1 - first number of first line: 1.1800
\D+
\d+                    # second number of first line: 100
[^\d-]+
-?\d*(?:\.\d+)?        # last number of first line: -0.200
\D+                    # skip second line
(?:                    # a data line: 18436 [LENZIE 618.0] -0.245 18433 [LENZIE 318.0] -0.245
  (?:                  # a data entry: 18436 [LENZIE 618.0] -0.245
    \d+                # first number in an entry: 18436
    \s+\[
    (.+?)              # group 2 - words in brackets: LENZIE
    -?\d*(?:\.\d+)?    # number in brackets: 618.0
    \]\s+
    \S+                # last number (VDEV): -0.245
    \s*
  )+
  (?=[\r\n\s]+|$)
)+
```

Comment: This is wonderful! If I wanted to match each section individually what would I change in the above regex?. For instance, if I only wanted to match the voltage deviation or the frequency these only change on the first line. One would be "BUSES WITH LOW VOLTAGE DEVIATION BELOW" and the other would be "BUSES WITH LOW FREQUENCY BELOW". Where would I insert this to make the match unique for each of thise groups.

Comment: oops I hit enter instead of space. I wanted to express my gratitude for your response. This will definitely save me a lot of time. I am also learning a great deal about regular expressions and how powerful they are. This will take me some time to understand, however I can use it while I learn. Thanks a million!!

Comment: @user1642486 You're welcome. I improved my answer to cover the point you commented. Please see if it solves the problem.

Comment: @user1642486 In StackOverflow, we upvote an answer if we find it helpful; we accept an answer if it solves our problem :)

Comment: I thought I already sent this but my computer is acting up. I ran the regex with the changes you suggested and it took a very long time to run (> one hour). Since I only need the time from the first line I am wondering if removing all the groups except the time and the item name (included within the square braces) would reduce the execution time.  I used the findall to pull all the matches, would it be better to use finditer instead since I will be checking each match for the item in [] and check the time if found? Thanks again! This has been more than an answer and more of a tutorial for me.

Comment: Just found where I could accept the answer. Will that close the post to further comments and refinements?

Comment: @user1642486 Improved the answer for performance, but I think they are slight improvements. Accepting answer doesn't freeze it, only marks it as 'solution'. Editing, commenting, deleting, all is still possible.

Comment: @user1642486 I tried improved version, it is matching and also your version is matching first section in the input in question, and first and last sections in the input in suggested edit. If it doesn't work for some input, the reason may be `-?\d*(?:\.\d+)?    # number in brackets: 618.0` part that you omitted.

Comment: I removed the section you referenced because I wanted to extract the entire content of the square bracket "[]". The regex matches everything except this "DNLP2G21.575" from the square bracket. I thought it was being filtered but it is not being captured. Thanks for helping.

Comment: I have identified at least 3 cases where the match fails but I am not sure where to put it. It is about 27 lines so it is not very long. Again, it matches in the majority of cases about 65 large files but fails in about 5 files and I don't know why.

Comment: @user1642486 Please provide failing examples, I will look at when I am available.

Comment: I added the examples. Also I note that the regex was only capturing the last match in each section (ie only the last [])

Answer (score 0):

You are wither trying to match `VOLT` with `VDEV`

```
(VFSCAN) AT TIME =  1.1800 UP TO  100 BUSES WITH LOW VOLTAGE DEVIATION BELOW -0.200:

X ----- BUS ------ X    VDEV       X ----- BUS ------ X    VDEV
```

or you are trying to match `-0.200` with `0.700`

```
(VFSCAN) AT TIME =  2.6267 UP TO  100 BUSES WITH LOW VOLTAGE BELOW  0.700:

X ----- BUS ------ X    VOLT       X ----- BUS ------ X    VOLT
```